# How to find duplicate records based on an id and a datetime field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, group-by, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection with millions of record. Sample records are shown below:

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("609977b0e8e1c615cb551bf5"),
    activityId: "123456789",
    updateDateTime: "2021-03-24T20:12:02Z"
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("739177b0e8e1c615cb551bf5"),
    activityId: "123456789",
    updateDateTime: "2021-03-24T20:15:02Z"
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("805577b0e8e1c615cb551bf5"),
    activityId: "123456789",
    updateDateTime: "2021-03-24T20:18:02Z"
  }
]
```

Multiple records could have the same `activityId`, in this case i want just the record that has the largest `updateDateTime`.

I have tried doing this and it works fine on a smaller collection but times out on a large collection.

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "MY_TABLE",
      let: {
        existing_date: "$updateDateTime",
        existing_sensorActivityId: "$activityId"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$activityId", "$$existing_sensorActivityId"] },
                { $gt: ["$updateDateTime", "$$existing_date"] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "matched_records"
    }
  },
  { $match: { "matched_records.0": { $exists: true } } },
  { $project: { _id: 1 } }
]
```

This gives me `_id`s for all the records which have the same activity id but smaller `updateDateTime`.

The slowness occurs at this step -> `"matched_records.0": {$exists:true}`

Is there a way to speed up this step or are there any other approach to this problem?

Comment: what is the use of lookup?, i can not see any details about second collection.

Comment: @turivishal To find duplicates in its own collection, I used the aggregation $lookup function to lookup into its own collection, like a SQL joining a table to itself.

Comment: okay your question is not clear, as per your title and this in your question *i want just the record that has the largest updateDateTime.*, what is exactly your expected result, 1) you want other documents that is not equal to latest one  2) need only latest document?

Comment: @turivishal apologies for the confusion. The goal for me is to get a list of all the duplicate ids so that I can delete them. so I would like to get 
1) you want other documents that is not equal to latest one

Comment: What if you filter unique documents and `$out` in new collection see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AJmGtCQC4Jo) for selecting unique documents.

Comment: @turivishal that might actually work! Thanks

Comment: @turivishal When i write it out the new collection is it possible for me to write out the contents of record object and not the record object itself?

Comment: I am not getting you actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find unique documents and write result in new collection using [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) instead of finding duplicate documents and deleting them,

**How to find unique documents?**

- `$sort` by `updateDateTime` in descending order
- `$group` by `activityId` and get first root record
- `$replaceRoot` to replace record in root
- [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to write query result in new collection

```
[
  { $sort: { updateDateTime: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$activityId",
      record: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$record" } },
  { $out: "newCollectionName" } // set new collection name
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AJmGtCQC4Jo)