# MongoDb aggregation delete duplicates according to parameter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, duplicates, aggregation-framework

I am trying to find out how I can make a mongodb aggregation to delete duplicate documents according to a specific parameter. When I say duplicates I don't mean that the whole document is the same.
For example I have the following documents:

```
{
  'event': 123,
  'element': 'element1'
},
{
  'event': 456
  'element': 'element2'
},
{
  'event': 789
  'element': 'element1'
},
{
  'event': 111
  'element': 'element3'
}
```

I would like to make an aggregation that if I specify the field "element" will return me all documents without element duplication. I know that the typical question is, ok but if there are two documents with 'element1' Which one do I want? the answer is that I dont mind if it returns me one or the other, this is why I dont know if this is possible

return example:

```
{
  'event': 123,
  'element': 'element1'
},
{
  'event': 456
  'element': 'element2'
},
{
  'event': 111
  'element': 'element3'
}
```

It is also OK if it returns me:

```
{
  'event': 456
  'element': 'element2'
},
{
  'event': 789
  'element': 'element1'
},
{
  'event': 111
  'element': 'element3'
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find duplicate records based on an id and a datetime field in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67504675/how-to-find-duplicate-records-based-on-an-id-and-a-datetime-field-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not deletion by any means. It's selection of documents with unique value in the field.

Such things are done by [grouping](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) documents by the field in question. Since you need any of the matching documents you can use [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#mongodb-group-grp.-first) accumulator:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$element",
      "doc": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$doc"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: It works!! tahnksMay I for example delete the duplicate accoriding to the maxium of some parameter

Comment: If by "delete duplicate" you mean select specific documents from the group - yes. You can  [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#mongodb-group-grp.-push) all documents into an array and add an extra stage to pick the one you need before the $replaceRoot stage.